# SQL Server : what does the '@@' symbol do?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am reading some stored procedures, and I stumbled upon some variables that are declared like this:

```
   set @@cstr1 = @@cKod1
   set @@pom1 = 1
```

What does the '@@' do? How is that different from '@'?

Comment: @Mat: Yeah, good luck finding that in the search engine...

Comment: Type `[sql-server] "@@"` in the search box here (with the quotes). Works just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

local variables which begins with single @ prefix, The scope of a variable is the range of Transact-SQL statements that can reference the variable. The scope of a variable lasts from the point it is declared until the end of the batch or stored procedure in which it is declared.

Global variables which begins with @@ prefix, you do not need to declare them, since the server constantly maintains them, they are system-defined functions not variables and do not have the same behaviors as variables. All the global variables represent information specific to the server or a current user sessions. Some of the commonly used ones are @@ERROR, @@IDENTITY, @@VERSION.

**Update:**
Declaring any variable with @@ prefix (except the system-defined) is actually a local variable.

Answer (score 2):

Local variables are declared by the user and can be used in procedures or in batches of SQL statements to hold information. Global variables are system-supplied variables that provide system-supplied values. All global variables have names beginning with two @ signs. For example, the global variable @@version has a value that is the current version number of the database engine. Users cannot define global variables.

But It's right to declare @@ as local variable